# What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

What is the difference between `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException`?

What causes them to be thrown? How can they be resolved?

I often encounter these throwables when modifying existing code to include new jar files.
I have hit them on both the client side and the server side for a java app distributed through webstart.

Possible reasons I have come across:

1. packages not included in `build.xml` for the client side of code
2. runtime classpath missing for the new jars we are using
3. version conflicts with previous jar

When I encounter these today I take a trail-and-error approach to get things working. I need more clarity and understanding.

Comment: I often find running the JVM with `-verbose` (e.g. `-verbose:class -verbose:jni`) helps — but mogsie reports below their answer that this provides no extra useful information :(

Answer (score 394, accepted):

The difference from the Java API Specifications is as follows.

For [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html):

> Thrown when an application tries to
>   load in a class through its string
>   name using:
>
> - The `forName` method in class `Class`.
> - The `findSystemClass` method in class `ClassLoader`.
> - The `loadClass` method in class `ClassLoader`.
>
> but no definition for the class with
>   the specified name could be found.

For [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or
>   a `ClassLoader` instance tries to load
>   in the definition of a class (as part
>   of a normal method call or as part of
>   creating a new instance using the new
>   expression) and no definition of the
>   class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition
>   existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition
>   can no longer be found.

So, it appears that the `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when the source was successfully compiled, but at runtime, the required `class` files were not found. This may be something that can happen in the distribution or production of JAR files, where not all the required `class` files were included.

As for `ClassNotFoundException`, it appears that it may stem from trying to make reflective calls to classes at runtime, but the classes the program is trying to call is does not exist.

The difference between the two is that one is an `Error` and the other is an `Exception`. With `NoClassDefFoundError` is an `Error` and it arises from the Java Virtual Machine having problems finding a class it expected to find. A program that was expected to work at compile-time can't run because of `class` files not being found, or is not the same as was produced or encountered at compile-time. This is a pretty critical error, as the program cannot be initiated by the JVM.

On the other hand, the `ClassNotFoundException` is an `Exception`, so it is somewhat expected, and is something that is recoverable. Using reflection is can be error-prone (as there is some expectations that things may not go as expected. There is no compile-time check to see that all the required classes exist, so any problems with finding the desired classes will appear at runtime.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` usually occurs when there's problem (exception thrown) with the static block or static fields initialization of the class, so the class can't be initialized successfully.

Comment: upvote. one is an `Error` and the other is an `Exception`. :)

Answer (score 83):

A ClassNotFoundException is thrown when the reported class is not found by the ClassLoader. This typically means that the class is missing from the CLASSPATH. It could also mean that the class in question is trying to be loaded from another class which was loaded in a parent classloader and hence the class from the child classloader is not visible. This is sometimes the case when working in more complex environments like an App Server (WebSphere is infamous for such classloader issues).

People often tend to confuse `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` however there's an important distinction. For example an exception (an error really since `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is a subclass of java.lang.Error) like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

does not mean that the ActiveMQConnectionFactory class is not in the CLASSPATH. Infact its quite the opposite. It means that the class ActiveMQConnectionFactory was found by the ClassLoader however when trying to load the class, it ran into an error reading the class definition. This typically happens when the class in question has static blocks or members which use a Class that's not found by the ClassLoader. So to find the culprit, view the source of the class in question (ActiveMQConnectionFactory in this case) and look for code using static blocks or static members. If you don't have access the the source, then simply decompile it using JAD.

On examining the code, say you find a line of code like below, make sure that the class SomeClass in in your CLASSPATH.

```
private static SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
```

Tip : To find out which jar a class belongs to, you can use the web site jarFinder . This allows you to specify a class name using wildcards and it searches for the class in its database of jars. jarhoo  allows you to do the same thing but its no longer free to use.

If you would like to locate the which jar a class belongs to in a local path, you can use a utility like jarscan ( http://www.inetfeedback.com/jarscan/ ). You just specify the class you'd like to locate and the root directory path where you'd like it to start searching for the class in jars and zip files.

Comment: It i funny that this is exactly correct answer voted the last. (Even -1 before I voted). ClassNotFoundException means the CL doesn't see .class file. NoClassDefFoundError means the .class file is there it is not loadable (possibly JNI error).

Comment: Isn't this answer contradicting with answer form coobird?

Comment: I tried similar example of Static block. My class Class1 has static variable "private static B foo = new B();" After compilation, I removed the B.class file from bin folder. Now from Main method of third class when I create object of Class1. The rror is thown as follws :-------- "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spring/B" ........ So it exactly mentiones which class it did not found i.e.class referred in static block and not the outer class.So it is contrary to this answer.

Comment: +1 for the clarification regarding "does not mean that the ActiveMQConnectionFactory class is not in the CLASSPATH"

Answer (score 37):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is a linkage error basically. It occurs when you try and instantiate an object (statically with "new") and it's not found when it was during compilation.

`ClassNotFoundException` is more general and is a runtime exception when you try to use a class that doesn't exist. For example, you have a parameter in a function accepts an interface and someone passes in a class that implements that interface but you don't have access to the class. It also covers case of dynamic class loading, such as using `loadClass()` or `Class.forName()`.

Answer (score 32):

A NoClassDefFoundError (NCDFE) happens when your code runs "new Y()" and it can't find the Y class.

It may simply be that Y is missing from your class loader like the other comments suggest, but it could be that the Y class isn't signed or has an invalid signature, or that Y is loaded by a different classloader not visible to your code, or even that Y depends on Z which couldn't be loaded for any of the above reasons.

If this happens, then the JVM will remember the result of loading X (NCDFE) and it will simply throw a new NCDFE every time you ask for Y without telling you why:

```
class a {
  static class b {}
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("First attempt new b():");
    try {new b(); } catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}
    System.out.println("\nSecond attempt new b():");
    try {new b(); } catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

*save this as a.java somewhere*

The code simply tries to instantiate a new "b" class twice, other than that, it doesn't have any bugs, and it doesn't do anything.

Compile the code with `javac a.java`, Then run a by invoking `java -cp . a` -- it should just print out two lines of text, and it should run fine without errors.

Then delete the "a$b.class" file (or fill it with garbage, or copy a.class over it) to simulate the missing or corrupted class.  Here's what happens:

```
First attempt new b():
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a$b
    at a.main(a.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a$b
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more

Second attempt new b():
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a$b
    at a.main(a.java:7)
```

The first invocation results in a ClassNotFoundException (thrown by the class loader when it can't find the class), which must be wrapped in an unchecked NoClassDefFoundError, since the code in question (`new b()`) should just work.

The second attempt will of course fail too, but as you can see the wrapped exception is no more, because the ClassLoader seems to remember failed class loaders.  You see only the NCDFE with absolutely no clue as to what really happened.

So if you ever see a NCDFE with no root cause, you need to see if you can track back to the very first time the class was loaded to find the cause of the error.

Comment: What about running the JVM with `-verbose`, or some similar option depending on the specific JVM? Probably `-verbose:class`, maybe `-verbose:class:jni` if using JNI, but I’m not sure about the syntax. If this is useful, perhaps you could show the results.

Comment: Neither `-verbose:class` nor `-verbose:jni` give any additional output relevant to the missing class.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, even if the result is disappointing. (P.S. I have since found out that `-verbose:class:jni` is wrong: one has to specify two separate options: `-verbose:class -verbose:jni`.)

Comment: The last sentence * 1,000,000: **So if you ever see a NCDFE with no root cause, you need to see if you can track back to the very first time the class was loaded to find the cause of the error.**

Answer (score 21):

From http://www.javaroots.com/2013/02/classnotfoundexception-vs.html:

**`ClassNotFoundException`** : occurs when class loader could not find the required class in class path. So, basically you should check your class path and add the class in the classpath.

**`NoClassDefFoundError`** : this is more difficult to debug and find the reason. This is thrown when at compile time the required classes are present, but at run time the classes are changed or removed or class's static initializes threw exceptions. It means the class which is getting loaded is present in classpath, but one of the classes which are required by this class are either removed or failed to load by compiler. So you should see the classes which are dependent on this class.

**Example**:

```
public class Test1
{
}


public class Test 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Test1 = new Test1();    
   }

}
```

Now after compiling both the classes, if you delete Test1.class file and run Test class, it will throw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
    at Test1.main(Test1.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

`ClassNotFoundException`: thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its name, but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

`NoClassDefFoundError`: thrown if the Java Virtual Machine tries to load in the definition of a class and no definition of the class could be found.

Comment: What about running the JVM with `-verbose`, or some similar option depending on the specific JVM? Probably `-verbose:class`, maybe `-verbose:class:jni` if using JNI, but I’m not sure about the syntax.

Comment: `-verbose:class:jni` is wrong, but you can pass two separate options: `-verbose:class -verbose:jni`.

Answer (score 15):

> What is the reason for getting each of them and any thought process on how to deal with such errors?

They're closely related. A `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when Java went looking for a particular class by name and could not successfully load it. A `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when Java went looking for a class that was linked into some existing code, but couldn't find it for one reason or another (e.g., wrong classpath, wrong version of Java, wrong version of a library) and is thoroughly fatal as it indicates that something has gone Badly Wrong.

If you've got a C background, a CNFE is like a failure to `dlopen()`/`dlsym()` and an NCDFE is a problem with the linker; in the second case, the class files concerned should never have been actually compiled in the configuration you're trying to use them.

Answer (score 11):

Example #1:

```
class A{
 void met(){
   Class.forName("com.example.Class1");
 }
}
```

If `com/example/Class1` doesn't exist in any of the classpaths, then It throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

Example #2:

```
Class B{
  void met(){
   com.example.Class2 c = new com.example.Class2();
 }
}
```

If `com/example/Class2` existed while compiling B, but not found while execution, then It throws `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Both are run time exceptions.

Answer (score 10):

Difference Between ClassNotFoundException Vs NoClassDefFoundError

[image]

Comment: Not crystal clear.  "Not updated in the classpath" is vague / imprecise.  This is about the either the JAR not being **present** in the classpath, or the **wrong version** of the JAR being on the classpath.  And spelling errors.  And (sigh) since you posted your information as a funky graphic, we can't fix this.

Answer (score 9):

[ClassNotFoundException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is thrown when there is attempt to load the class by referencing it via a String. For example the parameter to in Class.forName() is a String, and this raises the potential of invalid binary names being passed to the classloader.

The ClassNotFoundException is thrown when a potentially invalid binary name is encountered; for instance, if the class name has the '/' character, you are bound to get a ClassNotFoundException. It is also thrown when the directly referenced class is not available on the classpath.

On the other hand, [NoClassDefFoundError](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is thrown

- when the actual physical representation of the class - the .class file is unavailable,
- or the class been loaded already in a different classloader (usually a parent classloader would have loaded the class and hence the class cannot be loaded again),
- or if an incompatible class definition has been found - the name in the class file does not match the requested name,
- or (most importantly) if a dependent class cannot be located and loaded. In this case, the directly referenced class might have been located and loaded, but the dependent class is not available or cannot be loaded. This is a scenario where the directly referenced class can be loaded via a Class.forName or equivalent methods. This indicates a failure in linkage.

In short, a NoClassDefFoundError is usually thrown on new() statements or method invocations that load a previously absent class (as opposed to the string-based loading of classes for ClassNotFoundException), when the classloader is unable to find or load the class definition(s).

Eventually, it is upto the ClassLoader implementation to throw an instance of ClassNotFoundException when it is unable to load a class. Most custom classloader implementations perform this since they extend the URLClassLoader. Usually classloaders do not explicitly throw a NoClassDefFoundError on any of the method implementations - this exception is usually thrown from the JVM in the HotSpot compiler, and not by the classloader itself.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning 'the name in the class file does not match the requested name'. This is a quite common cause.

Answer (score 9):

> With the names itself we can easily identify one from `Exception` and other one is from `Error`.

**Exception:** Exceptions occurs during the execution of program. A programmer can handle these exception by try catch block. We have two types of exceptions. Checked exception which throws at compile time. Runtime Exceptions which are thrown at run time, these exception usually happen because of bad programming.

**Error:** These are not exceptions at all, it is beyond the scope of programmer. These errors are usually thrown by JVM.

---

[image]
[image source](http://ziuby.blogspot.in/2015/05/jvm-architecture.html)

**Difference:**

**ClassNotFoundException:**

- Class loader fails to **verify** a byte code in **Linking**.
- `ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception which occurs when an application tries to load a class through its fully-qualified name and can not find its definition on the classpath.
- `ClassNotFoundException` comes up when there is an **explicit loading** of class is involved by providing name of class at runtime using ClassLoader.loadClass(), Class.forName()  and ClassLoader.findSystemClass().

**NoClassDefFoundError:**

- Class loader fails **resolving** references of a class in **Linking**.
- `NoClassDefFoundError` is an Error derived from `LinkageError` class, which is a fatal error. It occurs when JVM can not find the definition of the class while trying to Instantiate a class by using the new keyword OR Load a class with a method call.
- `NoClassDefFoundError` is a result of **implicit loading** of class because of a method call from that class or any variable access.

---

**Similarities:**

- Both `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException` are related to unavailability of a class at run-time.
- Both `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError` are related to Java classpath.

Answer (score 3):

Given the Class loader sussystem actions:

[image: http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/images/fig7-1.gif]

This is an article that helped me a lot to understand the difference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html

> If an error occurs during class loading, then an instance of a
>   subclass of **LinkageError** must be thrown at a point in the program that
>   (directly or indirectly) uses the class or interface being loaded.
>
> If the Java Virtual Machine ever attempts to load a class C during
>   verification (§5.4.1) or resolution (§5.4.3) (but not initialization
>   (§5.5)), and the class loader that is used to initiate loading of C
>   throws an instance of **ClassNotFoundException**, then the Java Virtual
>   Machine must throw an instance of **NoClassDefFoundError** whose cause is
>   the instance of **ClassNotFoundException**.

So a *ClassNotFoundException* is a root cause of *NoClassDefFoundError*.
And a *NoClassDefFoundError* is a special case of type loading error, that occurs at **Linking** step.

Answer (score 2):

Add one possible reason in practise:

- ClassNotFoundException: as cletus said, you use interface while inherited class of interface is not in the classpath. E.g, Service Provider Pattern (or [Service Locator](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/ServiceLocator.html)) try to locate some non-existing class
- NoClassDefFoundError: given class is found while the dependency of given class is not found

In practise, ***Error*** may be thrown ***silently***, e.g, you submit a timer task and in the timer task it throws ***Error***, while in most cases, your program only catches ***Exception***. Then the ***Timer*** main loop is ended without any information. A similar Error to NoClassDefFoundError is [ExceptionInInitializerError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html), when your static initializer or the initializer for a static variable throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

**ClassNotFoundException** is a checked exception that occurs when we tell JVM to load a class by its string name using Class.forName() or ClassLoader.findSystemClass() or ClassLoader.loadClass() methods and mentioned class is not found in the classpath.

Most of the time, this exception occurs when you try to run an application without updating the classpath with required JAR files. For Example, You may have seen this exception when doing the JDBC code to connect to your database i.e.MySQL but your classpath does not have JAR for it.

**NoClassDefFoundError** error occurs when JVM tries to load a particular class that is the part of your code execution (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating an instance using the new keyword) and that class is not present in your classpath but was present at compile time because in order to execute your program you need to compile it and if you are trying use a class which is not present compiler will raise compilation error.

Below is the brief description

[image]

You can read [Everything About ClassNotFoundException Vs NoClassDefFoundError](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2017/04/Difference-Between-ClassNotFoundException-and-NoClassDefFoundError.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I remind myself the following again and again when I need to refresh

**ClassNotFoundException**

**Class Hierarchy**

```
ClassNotFoundException extends ReflectiveOperationException extends Exception extends Throwable
```

**While debugging**

1. Required jar, class is missing from the classpath.
2. Verify all the required jars are in classpath of jvm.

**NoClassDefFoundError**

**Class Hierarchy**

```
NoClassDefFoundError extends LinkageError  extends Error extends Throwable
```

**While debugging**

1. Problem with loading a class dynamically, which was compiled properly
2. Problem with static blocks, constructors, init() methods of dependent class and the actual error is wrapped by multiple layers [especially when you use spring, hibernate the actual exception is wrapped and you will get NoClassDefError]
3. When you face "ClassNotFoundException" under a static block of dependent class
4. Problem with versions of class. 
   This happens when you have two versions v1, v2  of same class under different jar/packages, which was compiled successfully using v1 and v2 is loaded at the runtime which doesn't has the relevant methods/vars& you will see this exception. [I once resolved this issue by removing the duplicate of log4j related class under multiple jars that appeared in the classpath]

Answer (score -1):

ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError occur when a particular class is not found at runtime.However, they occur at different scenarios.

ClassNotFoundException is an exception that occurs when you try to load a class at run time using Class.forName() or loadClass() methods and mentioned classes are not found in the classpath.

```
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at pack1.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)
```

NoClassDefFoundError is an error that occurs when a particular class is present at compile time, but was missing at run time.

```
    class A
    {
      // some code
    }
    public class B
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
        }
    }
```

When you compile the above program, two .class files will be generated. One is A.class and another one is B.class. If you remove the A.class file and run the B.class file, Java Runtime System will throw NoClassDefFoundError like below:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:10)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```