# Exporting jar and importing to a project in eclipse results NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar, export

Had a 3rd parties working JAR file in my own project, but I ran into a problem: i needed some customization to do.

1. Forked a repository from Github.
2. Modified the source code
3. Exported the JAR: Left click > Export > Java > JAR file > Default
   settings
4. Imported the JAR to my own Android project: Left click >
   Import > File system & Left Click on project > Properties >  Java
   Build Path > Add JARs > OK

Now, when I run my program (which was working fine with 3rd parties official JAR) I run into exception on runtime:

```
11-10 06:22:05.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
```

When I extract the JAR file, then it contains all the needed class files (including org.jsoup.Jsoup).

**NoClassDefFoundError** - *error reading the class definition. This typically happens when the class in question has static blocks or members which use a Class that's not found by the ClassLoader.* [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663810/noclassdeffounderror/6663937#6663937)

As I understand, this seems to be some kind of exported JAR classpath problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah , NoClassDefFoundError usually means the classpath problem , especially there are many class loaders. But I think yours is a simple case.

Are you sure it's " Java Build Path > Add JARs"?
It's a " Java Build Path > Add External JARs" option in my memory .Maybe you can try.