# I can't run java program in the CMD

Tags: java

I can't run the java program in the CMD,but it's OK in the eclipse.
[image]

These are my configures:

CLASSPATH:.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar

JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

PATH:%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin

I don't think there is something wrong with the program,because I am not successful in running even one program.All these programs come from the official website of Head First Java.I can use **javac** without any problems.

I can only provide these now.If you need more information.I'll provide it to you.

Comment: Check your classpath inside eclipse vs the global one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663810/noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Is the name of the class with `main()` `BeerSong`, not `beersong`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be in `f:\pro\hfjavafinalsamples` and run

```
java chap01.BeerSong
```

You need to give the `java` command the fully qualified class name, which according to the error message is `chap01.BeerSong`. Then `java` will look for the class `BeerSong` within the `chap01` package by checking in the `chap01` directory.

Note that Java is case-sensitive as well, even though the file system isn't - the class simple name is `BeerSong`, not `beersong`.

Comment: I read a few articles about this problem,I think the main problem is the "package".I just start to study the Java,and I have no concept of the "package".when I use the Eclipse,I often use the default package.So,I can't run my own program even by using the style you provided.However,I will try to solve this problem by getting more knowledge of Java.

Comment: @user911865: Well there were three problems in your approach: you weren't specifying the package name in the class name, you were in the wrong directory (the `chap01` directory instead of the "root" of your logical classpath), and you weren't using the right class name in terms of casing. I don't know why you think you "can't run" your own program using the approach I've given... you certainly will be able to. But yes, you should learn about packages very soon.

Comment: ,the first line of BeerSong is **package chap01**;but when I use Eclipse to create the class,I often use the default package,so there is no package declaration.I will try to solve this problem by myself,if I can't ,I'll ask you for help.Thank you!

Comment: @user911865: If you'd used the default package in this case, your class files would be in `f:\pro\hfjavafinalsamples` directly, and you'd just run `java BeerSong` - because in that case the fully-qualified class name would just be `BeerSong`