# NoClassDefFoundError accessing jackrabbit jar from servlet

Tags: spring-mvc, noclassdeffounderror, jackrabbit

I'm getting the above mentioned error when trying to access a repository
using jackrabbit-standalone-2.4.2.jar from a servlet. I didn't use the
jackrabbit war because I already have a thick client app working and I want
to reuse as much code as possible. I just assumed doing this was possible.

To test I created a small web application. Since I cannot attach a zip file
I will just copy the doPost() method below:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Repository repository = new TransientRepository(
       "repository.xml", //embedded within the war
       "path/to/home/dir");
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = repository.login();
        System.out.println("root node identifier: " +
        session.getRootNode().getIdentifier());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.logout();
    }
}
```

When I post to this servlet from an html form the exception has 2 parts:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jcr/Repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jcr.Repository
```

when I add jcr-2.0.jar in it then I get a different error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jackrabbit/core/TransientRepository
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You originally got the `ClassNotFoundException` because that class wasn't in the classpath. You have fixed that. The `NoClassDefFoundError` means the class *is* in the classpath, but there was an problem initializing it. For details about this distinction, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception).

So the class `TransientRepository` is there, but most likely a class referenced by the `TransientRepository` isn't. That means most likely you didn't include other required jar files in the classpath. For a complete list of dependencies (required jar files), see the `jackrabbit-standalone-2.4.2.jar`, or see the Jackrabbit docs. It could also mean you have all jar files, but at least one of the jar files is the wrong version.

Comment: Hi Thomas,
I double checked everything. The jars are included in my classpath and the versions are proper too. But still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You originally got the `ClassNotFoundException` because that class wasn't in the classpath. You have fixed that.

The `NoClassDefFoundError` means the class is in the classpath, but there was an problem initializing it.