# Possible reasons for NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I'm getting the following `NoClassDefFoundError`, which is weird because the class is already present in the library jar.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: abc/test/Test.java
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:795)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:144)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:75)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:294)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:288)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:287)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:327)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:795)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:144)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:75)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:294)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:288)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:287)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:327)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abc.test.Test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:299)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:288)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:287)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:327)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 25 more
```

This looks like its not able to find the same class which is causing the exception.
I have also included the library path in ant `build.xml`, which can be verified below.

```
<property name="deps" value="${lib}/abclib/abclib-test.jar"/>

<target name="dist" depends="compile">
        <manifest file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF">
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="xyz.test.TestConfiguration" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${deps}"/>
        </manifest>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/abc.jar" basedir="${build}/" manifest="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF" />
</target>
```

I'm lost, can someone at least guide me where should I look or what I might be doing wrong?

Also, can someone throw light, "Exception" and "Caused by". I'm not quite getting how are they two related.

Comment: How do you start your application? Could you please add the complete console command to your question?

Comment: How are you running it? (Command, location in directory tree, etc.) It's potentially interesting you get the `abc/test/test.java` text.

Comment: What is the value of the `lib` property?  For use in the manifest Class-Path it needs to be a relative path (using forward slashes), relative to the location of the main JAR file, not an absolute path (like you would get from `<property name="lib" location="lib"/>`).  I suggest you consider using the `manifestclasspath` task to massage your dependency classpath into the right format for use in a manifest.

Comment: @Andreas_D- I'm using `java -jar mcon.jar" with some other parameters. Also, I'm running it from the root directory of the project.

Comment: @DaveNewton- I have changed class and package names for the question. Its the same class as "abc.test.Test"

Comment: @IanRoberts- the value of `${lib}` is "lib" which is a folder inside the project root directory, so this can be one possible reason. How do I use `manifestclasspath`?

Comment: Caused by is an exception which was a cause of throwing another exception.

Comment: I've added an answer with more details on `manifestclasspath`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a really good explanation of the difference between `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException` in another [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception):

> does not mean that the ... class is not in the CLASSPATH. Infact its quite the opposite. It means that the class ... was found by the ClassLoader however when trying to load the class, it ran into an error reading the class definition. This typically happens when the class in question has static blocks or members which use a Class that's not found by the ClassLoader. So to find the culprit, view the source of the class in question ... and look for code using static blocks or static members.

You need to look at the code for Test.java and figure out what it imports and make sure those classes are on the classpath.  You could post the code of Test.java if you need help tracking the classes down.

Comment: Thanks that might be the reason, I'll look into the source code.

Answer (score 7):

**Initializing a static field with a function** may cause a hard to unveil `NoClassDefFoundError`

***Example: when you do something like this:***

```
public class SomePanel extends Panel {
    static int CALC_VALUE = ValueCalcUtils.calcValue();
    ...
```

***...where***

```
ValueCalcUtils.calcValue()
```

***... throws an Exception.***

Then, when the Exception is thrown, this will happen:

1. **There will be one single Error indicating on the actual Problem** (that `ValueCalcUtils.calcValue()` has thrown an Exception for some reason)
2. **Every subsequent try to create an instance of `SomePanel` will throw a (misleading) `NoClassDefFoundError` for `SomePanel`.**

This happens because the JVM will remember that `SomePanel` could not be initialized the first time he tried to create the class definition, and therefore does "not have a class definition" (`NoClassDefFoundError`) for `SomePanel` when asked again.

***In a Wicket/Tomcat situation ...***

I've had this exact Problem with a Wicket-Application on a Tomcat-Webserver. The Problem was, that the static Utils-Method relied on `WicketApplication.get()`.

Where this would work in most cases, it would lead to the described Problem when the Tomcat tried to restore old Sessions from the SessionStore on startup. Sometimes the Sessions contained serialized Instances of the Panel in Question. When initializing the Panel-Class there was an Exception because the **WicketApplication** did not yet exist on Tomcat startup.
Later on we had alot of confusing `NoClassDefFoundError`s for the Panel in our Application-Logs, without apparent reason.

**We finally found the single appearance of the "root Error" in the tomcat-stderror.log** file, since it was the tomcat throwing the initial error on startup.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError`..

While `first` one denote that the `class` you are using is not in your `classpath`

`Second` one denotes that, the `class` you are using is in turn using another `class` that is not in your classpath..

So, the problem is not that you don't have your class in classpath.. But the problem is, the `classes` on which your class is dependent is not in your classpath..
Now, you need to check what all `classes`, does your `class`(the one used currently in your code) depends upon..

Comment: My main class depends on `abc.test.Test` class which is inside a library, and I have included that library in my classpath.

Comment: And does your `abc.test.Test` class depend on any other class?? You need to add them also to the `library`.

Comment: The above class in inside a library, and as per the error its not able to find the same class which is causing the exception.

Comment: Actually I can't give you more valuable input, as you are using `Ant` buil file.. And I actually have no idea how a class is searched through an `Ant` build file.. Sorry.. May be you can look to other member's answer..

Answer (score 1):

The `Class-Path` entry in `MANIFEST.MF` has a specific format, in particular the entries in the classpath must be relative URIs (relative to the location of the JAR that contains the manifest).  Ant has a [`manifestclasspath` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) to help in constructing suitable classpaths.

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <property name="jar.location" location="${dist}/mcon.jar"/>
    <manifestclasspath property="manifest.class.path" jarfile="${jar.location}">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${deps}" />
      </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>
    <manifest file="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="xyz.test.TestConfiguration" />
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.class.path}"/>
    </manifest>
    <jar jarfile="${jar.location}" basedir="${build}/" manifest="${dist}/MANIFEST.MF" />
</target>
```

This should set up the `Class-Path` with the correct format (presumably something like `../lib/abclib/abclib-test.jar` in your example)

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the class was present during the compilation and not during the run time execution. So, as suggested by others you need to understand the classpath that is being used during the run time and not during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` thrown as a result that your classloader cannot load a definition of a class. Make sure the correct path of the class that is on the classpath is given. Check for the library is in classpath. Modify you `MANIFEST.MF` so that a library exist in `Class-Path`. Run java with the command line -cp switch to denote a library on the classpath.

Comment: I tried using `-cp` with absolute classpath, but still getting the same error.