# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils

Tags: java, tomcat

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils
```

I am getting this error. How to avoid this exception. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: put the XMLUtils jar file in your classpath.

Comment: Do you know what a NoClassDefFoundError means?

Comment: @AmanArora yes it is a web-app. i have build it using eclipse and den i have deployed it on tomcat.

Comment: Copy all the libraries in `WEB-INF/lib` and retsart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**According to Oracle:**

> `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

In simple language, it means "At compile-time `class` was there but at run-time, it failed to find/load the `class`
**Question comes : How come my code compile?**

Answer maybe because you added `jars` using Eclipse. But Eclipse does not actually move those `jars` into you `classpath`.It just uses those referenced `jars` while compilation. So your code compiles fine. 

After, you move your project to tomcat, when it tries to load some class inside those 'jars', it fails to find the `class`,because you never moved those `jars` to the classpath.
**Solution:**
Move all the `libraries(jars)` into your project's `/WEB-INF/lib`. Now all the `libraries/jars` under `/WEB-INF/lib` will come under `classpath`.

You can read more on [Oracle's Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) & [this article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply..but i have all the jars under /WEB-INF/lib folder, but still i am getting this exception..when i am running the project from eclipse it's working fine, but after deploying it on tomcat of Agile PLM its giving me this exception.

Comment: try to search for this class in the jars under `lib`.

Comment: Hi I have the class in the WEB-INF\lib\myjar. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This exception probably means that an instance has to be created by reflection, but the corresponding class is not in the execution classpath. Check your execution classpath.

It is also possible that the creation of the new instance depends on some configuration that is wrong or absent. Check your execution configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means, a library that was available at the compile time, is not available at the runtime.

In this case it's the jar file containing the class org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils. Make sure it is available in your classpath.

Comment: i have those jars in my class path.

Comment: How do you run the program? through command line? post your command if so.

Comment: i am running the web-app using tomcat. in one page  i am getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means the compiler trys to load the class at compile time but the required class is not available at compile time.

So add the required jar file  to your program. Can you add this jar file: axis-1.2.jar

Comment: The code compiled fine. At run-time, `JRE` is not able to find `class` to load.

Comment: what is diff bwn NoclassDefFoundError and class not found Exception

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: This [article](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/02/classnotfoundexception-vs.html) also has some info.