# What is the difference between ClassNotFoundException and ClassDefNotFoundException

Tags: java, oracle, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

What is the difference between [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) and [`ClassDefNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10926_01/doc/owb.101/b12155/oracle/owb/foundation/reflection/ClassDefNotFoundException.html) I know that both are subclass of `Exception`.

Got some explanation for `ClassNotFoundException` from this question. [*What is the difference between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)

I read [*Java doc*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10926_01/doc/owb.101/b12155/oracle/owb/foundation/reflection/ClassDefNotFoundException.html) for `ClassDefNotFoundException` and it says:

> *[ClassDefNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10926_01/doc/owb.101/b12155/oracle/owb/foundation/reflection/ClassDefNotFoundException.html) is thrown when the definition of a class cannot be found be the OWB typing system.*

Please elaborate above statement, I am unaware of OWB typing system. And what exactly is the difference between both the classed and when these Exceptions are raised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: @apomene I already mentioned that I was searching for `ClassDefNotFoundException` not `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException` I don't think this is duplicate.

Comment: I want difference between `ClassNotFoundException` and `ClassDefNotFoundException` not between `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. A more pertinent question would be what exactly *is* ClassDefNotFoundException. It's very poorly documented.

Comment: ClassDefNotFoundException is not a standard java exception whereas ClassNotFoundException is a part of standard java. You should check Oracle Warehouse Builder documentation to understand when is CLassDefNotFoundException thrown

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` is a core Java exception.

`ClassDefNotFoundException` is an "Oracle Warehouse Builder" exception (which in all likelihood just wraps a `ClassNotFoundException`).

Comment: Please elaborate how `ClassDefNotFoundException` wraps `ClassNotFoundException`? as `ClassDefNotFoundException` is a subclass of `java.lang.Exception` neither I see any use of `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: I'm not an OWB user, so I'm speculating here. Since `ClassDefNotFoundException` is an exception specific to OWB, I'd assume that it's being created in response to a `ClassNotFoundException` being thrown.

Comment: appreciate your finding.

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when the reported class is not found by the ClassLoader. This typically means that the `class is missing from the CLASSPATH`.

Suppose we have a class named as X has reference to Class Y. Classloader loads the class X, It's loaded now it goes through `linking phase` where it goes through three different subphases.

1. Verification-phase
2. Prepare-phase
3. Resolve-phase.

Now when it goes through `Resolve-phase` and this phase try to resolve reference of Y and unfortunately it does not find the definition of class Y, then It will be `ClassDefNotFoundException` for Class Y and it will wrap 'ClassNotFoundException' for class X.