# Using GWT and a library that uses log4j in the same project

Tags: java, gwt, jar, log4j

I'm developing a GWT web app. As well as GWT, I'm using a .jar that also uses logj4, which I will call "bob". If I don't add the log4j jar into my `war/WEB-INF/lib` folder, I get the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338387/unexpected-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-log4j-logmanage): `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager`.

If I do put the .jar in the `lib` folder, I get another `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, this time for `org/apache/log4j/Appender`. The error comes from within "bob", my other library. Bob.jar is on the classpath of the project, as well as in `war/WEB-INF/lib`.

Is there an obvious fix to this?

Comment: Is "bob" used at client side too or only server side? If only server side, try putting it **only** in `WEB-INF/lib` (and specifically *not* on the classpath for GWT DevMode). Also, which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: Like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338387/unexpected-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-log4j-logmanage does it help if you put BOTH log4j12 and log4j2 jars in WEB-INF/lib?