# java NoClassDefFoundError with maven dependency (log4j)

Tags: java, maven, log4j, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to make a little program using maven. I'm using a template from a prof at my university and I'd like to use log4j for logging.
When I run the program in eclipse it works fine. However when I create the jar with "mvn install" and try to run the program in cmd I get a NoClassDefFoundError

```
C:\eclipse_workspace_buchhaltung\Buchhaltung\target>c:\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java.exe -jar Buchhaltung-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
        at ch.hslu.demo.DemoKlasse.<clinit>(DemoKlasse.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

The DemoKlasse I'm using to try out things looks like the following:

```
package ch.hslu.demo;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class DemoKlasse {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DemoKlasse.class); // that's line 11

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("DemoKlasse gestartet: " + LocalDateTime.now());

        System.out.println("Dies ist eine Testklasse!");
        String eingabe = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie etwas ein. Beenden mit \"exit\"");

            eingabe = sc.nextLine();

            logger.info("Eingabe lautet: " + eingabe);

            if(eingabe.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Das Programm wird beendet");
                logger.info("Exit wurde eingegeben: " + LocalDateTime.now());
                sc.close();
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My pom with the log4j part looks like this:

```
    <properties>
        ...
        <log4j2.version>2.12.1</log4j2.version>
        <junit5.version>5.5.1</junit5.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            ...
```

I've also found this here: [NoClassDefFoundError on Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)
I tried using the maven-shade-plugin and the maven-assembly-plugin but I still can't make it work.

Has anyone an idea why I can't make such a simple program work?

Comment: If you are not using any plugin like shade/assembly and so on to create a uber jar, dependencies don't get packaged.  If it is just default jar generated by maven will have only your classes not the dependencies.

Comment: You can check the content of your jar by extracting it, and see what are all the classes is packaged inside.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338387/unexpected-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-log4j-logmanage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What are you doing?

You are creating a JAR file containing your code (and a Manifest file that points to your main class).

## What is the problem?

You are exporting your code to a JAR file but the dependencies are not exported. Obviously, your program needs the dependencies to run(logging libriaries are not essention but other libs are).

## How to solve it?

You said, you tried the shadow and the assembly plugin. You can add the dependencies with both. I think you just configured it incorrectly.

With the `maven-assembly-plugin`, you need to create a `jar-with-dependencies` and you shouldn't forget about your main class.

For example, you could use the following configuration(replace `fully-qualified-main-class` with the package name of your main class followed by the name of the main class(seperated by dots):

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest> 
        </archive> 
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After that, you can create the JAR with the command `mvn package`.

Make sure to execute the `jar-with-dependencies` and not the JAR created by the `maven-jar-plugin`.

## other possible problems

It is possible that your program declares log4j with the scope `provided`. In that case, log4j is not included in your `jar-with-dependencies`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/10871900

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Now I understand what the problem was and what the solution does and it also works for my program.