# Wired java class initializing issue on windows. Is there an approach to locate the issue?

Tags: java, spring, class

Ecountered a wired problem yestoday, the phenominon is that some of my java web apps could not be started because of class initialing or reflection issues.

One app throws an error: could not find useful constructor when trying to call Constructor.newInstance, but the class do have a public constructor without parameters, and it running normal days before, no code changed on this class or its super class.

Another app throws `NoClassDefFound: "Could not initialize class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`" when I start it in IDEA, but when I tried to start it in a local tomcat, it throws the same error on com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0Defaults. I packaged the app to a war file and send it to one of my colleges, however the error didn't occur.

Solutions I've tried util now:

1. Restarting my IDE
2. Restarting my system
3. Run the apps in a VM
4. Reinstall my JDK 1.7.0_51
5. Switch to my ubuntu system, errors not shown then.(I have 2 system, windows and ubuntu installed)

My guess is that something with my JDK, but I don't know how to locate and resolve that.

Here I paste some of the errors below:

1.

```
2014-12-25 14:44:33 [DEBUG] o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory ->  Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'creditPeriodRuleMapper' defined in file [E:\workspace\tz\tops-finance-core\out\artifacts\tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\com\travelzen\tfc\billing\client\CreditPeriodRuleMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/E:/workspace/tz/tops-finance-core/out/artifacts/tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring/tfc-fin-ctx-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tfc-dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tfc-dataSource' defined in URL [file:/E:/workspace/tz/tops-finance-core/out/artifacts/tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring/tfc-fin-ctx-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tfc-dataSource-master' while setting bean property 'defaultTargetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tfc-dataSource-master' defined in URL [file:/E:/workspace/tz/tops-finance-core/out/artifacts/tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring/tfc-fin-ctx-dao.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0Defaults; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/E:/workspace/tz/tops-finance-core/out/artifacts/tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring/tfc-fin-ctx-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tfc-dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tfc-dataSource' defined in URL [file:/E:/workspace/tz/tops-finance-core/out/artifacts/tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring/tfc-fin-ctx-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tfc-dataSource-master' while setting bean property 'defaultTargetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tfc-dataSource-master' defined in URL [file:/E:/workspace/tz/tops-finance-core/out/artifacts/tfc_fin_web_Web_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/spring/tfc-fin-ctx-dao.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0Defaults
```

2.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:170)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5372)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1646)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-12-25 14:45:49 [WARN] o.s.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext ->  Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 25 14:45:46 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5372)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1646)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Does c3P0*.jar exists in your classpath or WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @almasshaikh Yes, if not, the error would be ClassNotFoundError instead of NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: You need to read either java doc or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception) link