# Fatal Exception AsyncTask #1 in uploading in android

Tags: java

Im trying to capture and upload an image using google glass, following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) codes and im not getting any response nor error. This is my LOG. Thanks for any help

```
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    Process: info.androidhive.glassmenu, PID: 21277
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:314)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:240)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info.androidhive.glassmenu.AndroidMultiPartEntity
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at  info.androidhive.glassmenu.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile(UploadActivity.java:87)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at info.androidhive.glassmenu.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:76)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at info.androidhive.glassmenu.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:1)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:302)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-29 16:11:32.011: E/AndroidRuntime(21277):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: I dont see any problem with my AndroidMultipartEntity class, what does it cause?

Comment: Please See the Answers on [NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)