# ClassNotFoundException vs NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have gone through this thread [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)
This is what one of the ans,which has max ups,  in thread is :
**NoClassDefFoundError** :"So, it appears that the NoClassDefFoundError **occurs when the source was successfully compiled, but at runtime, the required class files were not found**. This may be something that can happen in the distribution or production of JAR files, where not all the required class files were included."

**ClassNotFoundException** : As for ClassNotFoundException, it appears that it may stem from trying to make reflective calls to classes at runtime, but the classes the program is trying to call is does not exist.

I did a small experiment . I created a main class, **class A** and tried to call other class, class **B** from it , compiled successfully.

Then i deleted the class B which is being called in class A.
I got the  **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** but as per the answer in the tread, i should have got NoClassDefFoundError (source was compiled succesfully but at runtime class files were not found)
Could anyone explain what am i missing in the interpretation of the ans in the thread  ?

```
package com.random;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b= new B();

    }

}

 package com.random;

public class B {



}
```

Comment: Interesting, because another site did the same test and got the result you're looking for: http://www.javaroots.com/2013/02/classnotfoundexception-vs.html

Comment: I'd be curious to see what would happen if you put class B in a different package and then had to include `import com.random.blah.B;` in class A.

Comment: Interesting. After deleting B.class I got this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/random/B
 at com.random.A.main(A.java:6)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.random.B

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**NoClassDefFoundError**

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

---

**ClassNotFoundException**

> Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string
>   name using: The forName method in class Class. The findSystemClass
>   method in class ClassLoader . The loadClass method in class
>   ClassLoader.

---

You have to understand that the `JVM` can't realize the definition of the `class` you deleted can't be found, as the `class` itself can't be found which automatically throw the `ClassNotFoundException`.

This exception happen at `runtime` so it does not matter if it compiled first or not, you deleted the file, therefore it can't be found and throw the `exception`.

Note that `NoClassDefFoundError` is not actually an exception, it is an `Error` derived from `LinkageError` while `ClassNotFoundException` derive directly from `java.lang.Exception`.

To resume, the `NoClassDefFoundError` globally simply mean that the `JVM` tried to access at `runtime` something that according to the `compiled` code should exists, but does not actually exist (or is not in the classpath).

---

**Example to reproduce ClassNotFoundException**

```
public class ClassNotFoundExceptionExample {

    private static final String CLASS_TO_LOAD = "main.java.Utils";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class loadedClass = Class.forName(CLASS_TO_LOAD);
            System.out.println("Class " + loadedClass + " found successfully!");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("A ClassNotFoundException was caught: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example to reproduce NoClassDefFoundError**

Create a simple class `Test`

```
public class Test {
        public Test() {
                System.out.println("A new instance of the Test class was created!");
        }
}
```

And a class `NoClassDefFoundErrorExample`

```
public class NoClassDefFoundErrorExample {
        private static Test test = new Test();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("The definition of Test was found!");
        }
}
```

Now create a n executable `.jar` which execute the `main` method. You can specify it in the `Manifest.txt` file inside the `.jar`

```
Main-Class: NoClassDefFoundErrorExample
```

Now run the following commands

```
javac Test.java
javac NoClassDefFoundErrorExample.java
jar cfm NoClassDefFoundErrorExample.jar Manifest.txt NoClassDefFoundErrorExample.class
java -jar NoClassDefFoundErrorExample.jar
```

Notice the `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestClass
    at NoClassDefFoundErrorExample.(NoClassDefFoundErrorExample.java:2)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: The stack trace erroneously complains about `TestClass` while it should mention `Test`.

Answer (score 13):

Well... `ClassNotFoundException` occurs when the runtime is trying to find the class named by some `String` for example `Class.forName(java.lang.String)` method take a string argument and tries to find the class with this name. In this case the class-name is a sting and can only be checked at runtime. here the exception clearly says... this "class" is not found. So... it can happen for two reasons :

Reason 1. Class-name is not a valid java-class ( example - "java.bang.kiting").

```
// Example    
Class cdef = Class.forName( "java.bang.kiting" );
```

Reason 2. Class-name is was a valid class... but somehow it was not packaged with the jar or is not resolved in class-path. So as far as the runtime knows... it can be a wrong class name... similar to case 1.

```
// Example    
Class cdef =Class.forName( "apache.some.SomeLegitClass" );
```

Where as `NoClassDefFoundError` for cases where the actual class reference was used,

```
// example
import apache.some.SomeLegitClass
SomeLegitClass i = (SomeLegitClass) instanceOfSomeLegitClass;
```

So basically the everything was correct but somehow the class is not packaged with the jar ( or more generally - is not resolved in the class-path ). In this case we get `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Here runtime knows that the class is valid since it compiled successfully...  but it can not find the "class definition".

Comment: "Here runtime knows that the class is valid since it compiled successfully... but it can not find the "class definition" - this line is the essence of this ans

Answer (score 13):

The **difference depends on who asked the class to be loaded**:

- **`ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when the code is directly trying to load a class**, passing the `String` argument representing a Fully Qualified Name of the class.

  - e.g. `Class.forName(String)`, or `ClassLoader.loadClass(String)`.
- **`NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when the JVM is asked to load a class indirectly**.

  - e.g. when class A is using class B and class B is not on classpath, `NoClassDefFoundError` will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is usually called when you are using a library(for example, Guava, Gson, CommonsIO). You put the library in classpath of your project, but you didn't export it together, you will get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when the application is running.

How to get `NoClassDefFoundError`:
Create a new project, with this class.

```
public class A
{
    public void do()
    {
        System.out.println("Do!");
    }
}
```

Export it as a `.jar`file.

Now create another project. Add the exported jar file to classpath.

```
import ???.A;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.do();//NoClassDefFoundError thrown at here.
    }
}
```

Export the project, make sure you do not include the jar file(with class `A`). Run the newly exported jar file, you will see that error!

Answer (score 2):

**1)** **ClassNotFoundException**

1. This occurs, when we try to load a class at run-time using `Class.forName()` or `ClassLoader.loadClass()` or `ClassLoader.findSystemClass()` methods and it could **not** find the required class in the **class path**.
2. In this case, we should check the `class path` and add the class in the class path if it is missing.
3. This is a **checked Exception**, which is derived from **java.lang.Exception** class    .
4. This comes under **explicit** loading.

**2)** **NoClassDefFoundError**

1. This occurs, when the class was present during the `compile time` and is not available during `run time` for some reasons. It means the class which is getting loaded is `present` in `classpath` , but one of the dependent `classe(s)` which are required by this class are either **removed** or **failed** to load by the compiler.
2. In this case, we only need to check the `classes which are dependent on this class`.
3. This is an **Error**, which is derived from **java.lang.LinkageError**.
4. This comes under **implicit** loading.

Comment: It always confuses. In given example in question class B is indirectly referred by class A. class A depends on class B, so it should throw NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 2):

[Everything About ClassNotFoundException Vs NoClassDefFoundError](https://programmingmitra.com/2017/04/Difference-Between-ClassNotFoundException-and-NoClassDefFoundError.html) article explains the difference between ClassNotFoundException Vs NoClassDefFoundError very clearly with example and according to it.

[image: ClassNotFoundException Vs NoClassDefFoundError -- Programming Mitra]

### **ClassNotFoundException**

Is a checked exception that occurs when we tell JVM to load a class by its string name using Class.forName() or ClassLoader.findSystemClass() or ClassLoader.loadClass() methods and mentioned class is not found in the classpath.

Most of the time, this exception occurs when you try to run an application without updating the classpath with required JAR files. For Example, You may have seen this exception when doing the JDBC code to connect to your database i.e.MySQL but your classpath does not have the jar for it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Provide any class name to Class.forName() which does not exist
        // Or compile Test.java and then manually delete Person.class file so Person class will become unavailable
        // Run the program using java Test

        Class clazz = Class.forName("Person");
        Person person = (Person) clazz.newInstance();
        person.saySomething();
    }
}

class Person {
    void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

### **NoClassDefFoundError**

Is a subtype of java.lang.Error and Error class indicates an abnormal behavior which really should not happen with an application but and application developers should not try to catch it, it is there for JVM use only.

NoClassDefFoundError occurs when JVM tries to load a particular class that is the part of your code execution (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating an instance using the new keyword) and that class is not present in your classpath but was present at compile time because in order to execute your program you need to compile it and if you are trying use a class which is not present compiler will raise compilation error.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Do javac on Test.java, 
        // Program will compile successfully because Empoyee class exits
        // Manually delete Employee.class file
        // Run the program using java Test
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.saySomething();

    }
}

class Employee {
    void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answers, NoClassDefFoundError will occur when the class was present during the compile time and is not available during run time for some reasons.

There is another scenario I wish to add, which could also result in NoClassDefFoundError.

When you are trying to load a class which failed to load due to some exception say failure in static initialization block, system will throw you ExceptionInInitializerError. If you **try to load the same class again (which failed to load previously), system will throw NoClassDefFoundError**

Lets explore it with an sample

**ClassWithStaticBlock.java**

```
public class ClassWithStaticBlock {

    static {
       int total = 1/0;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassWithStaticBlock cs;
    try {
       cs = new ClassWithStaticBlock();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at ClassWithStaticBlock.<clinit>(ClassWithStaticBlock.java:7)
    ... 6 more
```

Lets modify **Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassWithStaticBlock cs;
        try {
           cs = new ClassWithStaticBlock();
        }catch(Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cs = new ClassWithStaticBlock(); //try to use ClassWithStaticBlock again
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at ClassWithStaticBlock.<clinit>(ClassWithStaticBlock.java:7)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClassWithStaticBlock
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

When we try to use ClassWithStaticBlock again (which failed to initialize earlier), System is throwing NoClassDefFoundError.

Found the sample from [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

One of cases where NoClassDefFoundError occur is when the Class JVM is trying to access is not found in classpath.
But if class is present in classpath, It will result in ClassNotFoundException.

In short NoClassDefFoundError will come if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.

Just try to run with explicit -classpath option where the classpath does not contain class B.

Comment: Why would you get a `ClassNotFoundException` if the class is present in the classpath?

Answer (score -2):

The other answers in this thread are correct, i just want to add something i spent hours trying to figure out. Even if

```
Class.forName("apache.some.SomeLegitClass")
```

works,

```
Class.forName("apache.some.somelegitclass")
```

will result in a NoClassDefFoundError. The Class.forName() is case-sensitive. It will result in different exceptions if the classname is spelled wrong, or simply has incorrect casing.