# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster

Tags: java, classpath, cassandra-2.1

the existing stackoverflow questions on this topic all indicate I have a classpath issue. However, it looks to be correct.  Any help greatly appreciated. TIA.

```
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME; echo $PATH 
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_71
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_71/bin
~$



~$ ll /usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 990392 May  2 21:36 /usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar
~$ 



~$ java -classpath ./:/usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar -jar CassandraFunctionalTests.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster
    at com.seagate.bdcauto.cassandratests.CassandraLabConnector.<init>(CassandraLabConnector.java:13)
    at com.seagate.bdcauto.cassandratests.FunctionalTests.main(FunctionalTests.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
~$
```

Comment: The Cluster class is in the cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar

Comment: Add the mentioned jar to classpath and Show your classpath

Comment: @Rao  ~$ java -classpath ./:/usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar -jar CassandraFunctionalTests.jar

Comment: Can you try this? `java -classpath .:/usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar:$CLASSPATH -jar CassandraFunctionalTests.jar`

Comment: @Rao  
~$ java -classpath .:/usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar:$CLASSPATH -jar CassandraFunctionalTests.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster
 at com....

Comment: Can you check `jar -tvf /usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar | grep Cluster` and see if that shows up. Are you confident that it is the jar? And this time exception is changed, right? May be you need to visit your classes to see why `NoClassDefFoundError` coming.

Comment: Yep:  
~$ jar tvf /usr/local/cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar | grep Cluster.class
 12059 Thu Jan 28 16:08:24 CST 2016 com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.class
  3077 Thu Jan 28 16:08:26 CST 2016 com/datastax/driver/core/DelegatingCluster.class
~$

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322833/classnotfoundexception-vs-noclassdeffounderror) or [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/07/classnotfoundexception-vs.html) to understand the  issue.

Comment: May be you want to show the code around `CassandraLabConnector.java:13`

Comment: cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("11.49.5.43 11.49.5.47 11.49.5.53")
            .withCredentials("USERNAME","PASSWORD")
            .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM))
            .build();