# Spark and Prediction IO: NoClassDefFoundError Despite Dependency Existing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, mesos, predictionio

**Problem:**

I am attempting to train a Prediction IO project using Spark 1.6.1 and PredictionIO 0.9.5, but the job fails immediately after the Executors begin to work. This happens both in a Stand-Alone spark cluster and a Mesos cluster. In both cases I am deploying to the cluster from a remote client i.e. I am running `pio train -- --master [master on some other server]` .

**Symptoms:**

- In the driver logs, shortly after the first `[Stage 0:>    (0 + 0) / 2]` message, the executors die due to `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil`

**Investigation:**

- Found the class-in-question within the `pio-assembly` jar:

  ```
  jar -tf pio-assembly-0.9.5.jar | grep ProtobufUtil
  org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/ProtobufUtil$1.class
  org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/ProtobufUtil.class
  ```
- When submitting, this jar is deployed with the project and can be found within the executors
- Adding `--jars pio-assembly-0.9.5.jar` to `pio train` does not fix the problem
- Creating an uber jar with `pio build --clean --uber-jar` does not fix the problem
- Setting `SPARK_CLASSPATH` on the slaves to a local copy of `pio-assembly-0.9.5.jar` **does** solve the problem

As far as I am aware, `SPARK_CLASSPATH` is deprecated and should be replaced with `--jars` when submitting. I'd rather not be dependant on a deprecated feature. Is there something I am missing when calling `pio train` or with my infrastructure? Is there a defect (e.g. race condition) with the executors fetching the dependencies from the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class` doesn't actually mean that the dependency is not there, but rather it is a poorly named exception and the real problem is that the class loader had trouble loading the class. The actual problem will be reported in the form of `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` which will likely be thrown from a static code block. It is hard to tell the difference between`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, but the latter is what actually means that the dependency is missing ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322833/classnotfoundexception-vs-noclassdeffounderror) and others provide more details).