# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSBuilder spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on Spark java application that should load a json file. Application successfully loads avro file but gets the below error while loading json file.

```
sparksession.read().json(hdfs_path_of_file) -- loading json file doesn't work
sparksession.read().format(avro).load(hdfs_path_of_file) -- loading avro file works
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSBuilder
```

My dependencies are-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.4.7.7.1.7.48-2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.4.7.7.1.7.48-2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.4.7.7.1.7.48-2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.4.7.7.1.7.48-2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Why can't `FSBuilder` be found even when `hadoop-common` is there? Also, `FSBuilder` is an interface and not a class, but I assume JVM classloader loads both classes as well as interfaces.

Comment: If you're working on Spark, then add Spark dependencies. Those already include hdfs client as a transitive dependency.... You don't need the rest of your dependencies here to run the code you've shown

Comment: We have added spark dependencies as well like spark core, spark sql, spark avro and spark hive

Comment: These dependencies were already there but i still don't understand why it can't find a particular class

Comment: Worth noting that `NoClassDefFoundError` is not the same as `ClassNotFoundException`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322833/classnotfoundexception-vs-noclassdeffounderror. TLDR The former is often seen when **the dependencies** of a class being loaded are not found in classpath, at runtime, not the class itself.

Comment: Please show your complete POM as a [mcve] if you do have Spark dependencies. Also what Spark version do you have installed?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've added spark dependencies as well in my answer. My pom is 800 lines long, I highly doubt if i can paste that entire thing over here

Comment: Thanks, so I suspect your problem is that Spark 2.4.7 isn't using Hadoop 3 libraries, so you manually adding them is causing conflicts. As I stated before, Spark includes HDFS dependencies itself, so what exactly is the error you're getting when you remove the ones you've added? Also, you should add provided scope to the Spark dependencies. (and I highly doubt you should be excluding so much unless you want other class not found exceptions)