# How do I get this RoutingAppender to work correctly, in Log4J ?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, flume-ng

I have the following Log4J XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="OutputLogFile.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>

    <Flume name="AuditLogger" compress="true">

    <!--  <Agent host="localhost" port="8800"/> 
      <RFC5424Layout enterpriseNumber="18060" includeMDC="true" appName="MyApp"/>  
    -->

    </Flume>

    <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${sd:type}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${sd:type}" fileName="${sd:type}.log"
                       filePattern="${sd:type}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100" />
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
         <!--  <Route ref="AuditLogger" key="Audit"/>  -->
      </Routes>
    </Routing>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <Appender-Ref ref="Console"/>
      <Appender-Ref ref="MyFile"/>  <!-- added_in now -->

    </Root>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Is this the way to implement the RoutingAppender? My goal is to break up the logging , so that when my application logs (with `logger.debug("This is debug");` ) messages, then it will break up the log files into many separate logs (something like LogOutput1.log , LogOutput2.log , LogOutput3.log , etc.  ).

But it seems I'm missing the idea here. Apache Flume doesn't work with me, and I've been getting this eror :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flume/Even
t
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.creat
eBuilder(PluginBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build
(PluginBuilder.java:120)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPlug
inObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigur
e(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(Abst
ractConfiguration.java:161)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerCo
ntext.java:361)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext
.java:426)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext
.java:442)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
138)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log
4jContextFactory.java:207)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log
4jContextFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:160)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:492)
        at sample_server.<clinit>(sample_server.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.Event
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 19 more
```

Any tips /hints greatly appreciated , thanks/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - thats subtle ! I am reading up on this ,  thank you !!!