# Where java compiler keeps its import mapping

Tags: java, import, package

I am new to java. I want to know when I write

`import {SOME_PACKAGE_NAME}`

where does it search for the folder? Is there any general folder or mapping file where it search for given package?

Comment: It searches in the classpath

Comment: It searches directories specified in classpath (argument you passed with `java` command), or `yourJavaRuntimeEnvironment/lib/rt.jar` (for standard classes like `java.util.List`).

Comment: @Pshemo not `java` but `javac`. Runtime knows nothing about imports.

Comment: Wiki page of interest to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29 . Be careful with "I'm new to Java" type of questions though; the chance is immensely high that whatever question you have to ask is already asked before.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. but i tried to search it but may be i did not know the exact words to search.. @Gimby

Answer (score 5):

All the directories of your project and from Jar's will be added to class path. From there classes being imported from the `classpath`.

You will see errors if compiler doesn't found them at compile time.

If they are not found  at runtime [`ClassNotFoundException's/NoClassDefFoundError`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)'s based on the case occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Imports in Java don't have the same semantics as `require` or similar in dynamic languages. They do not point to folders or modules; they are just used for type name resolution: to convert a simple name into a fully qualified name. It is equivalent to use the full name in code:

```
new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Where the compiler will locate the definition of `java.util.ArrayList` or any other class is not specified and in practice it will be either in the JRE library, a JAR added to the compiler's classpath, or inside the same source code project as a .java file.

Note particularly that the location of the class during compilation may be completely different than at runtime: when you compile code for a Java EE container, locally you'll have an archive of the Java EE interfaces to refer to, but at runtime these will be classes provided by the container.