# NoClassDefFoundError while using spring aop

Tags: java, spring

I have gone through other question based on this topic but they didn't help.

This is my **SpringConfiguration.xml**:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="game" class="SpringAoP.Game"></bean>

    <bean id="audience" class="SpringAoP.Audience"></bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="audience">
            <aop:pointcut id="play" expression="execution(* SpringAoP.Game.Play(..))"></aop:pointcut>
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="play"  method="takeSeats"></aop:before>
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="play"  method="shout"></aop:before>
            <aop:after method="applaud" pointcut-ref="play"></aop:after>
            <aop:after-throwing  method="badApplaud" pointcut-ref="play"></aop:after-throwing>

        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>


</beans>
```

This is my **Game.java:**

```
package SpringAoP;


public class Game {

    public void Play(){
        System.out.println("Game Started");
    }
    public void enter(){
        System.out.println("Jump Jump wowowowowowwwhahaaa");
    }
}
```

This is my **Audience.java**:

```
package SpringAoP;

public class Audience {
    //before match
    public void takeSeats(){
        System.out.println("Audience are now seated");
    }

    public void shout(){
        System.out.println("Manchester Utd  ! OOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOOOOOOOOOOOO");
    }

    //after match
    public void applaud(){
        System.out.println("TATATATATATATATATATA!!! Great Game");
    }

    public void badApplaud(){
        System.out.println("boooooooo ! Bad Game");
    }
}
```

This is my main class:

```
package SpringAoP;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


    public class StartGame {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Game.xml");

            Game football = (Game) ac.getBean("game");
            football.enter();
        }
    }
```

When I run the program I get a **NoClassDefFoundError**:

This is the *stackTrace*:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [Game.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at SpringAoP.StartGame.main(StartGame.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.getAdviceClass(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:411)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.createAdviceDefinition(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:367)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parseAdvice(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parseAspect(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:228)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 63 more
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: this kind of error occur only when some jar is missing or not given to build tool. check your project build setup. i am working in eclispe, i have no idea about netbean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [aopalliance](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance) in your dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using netbeans! can u please tell me how i can do that

Comment: I know how to add jar files!! can u get me the link for aopalliance

Comment: @Jois, Suggestion: use build tools to manage your dependency, like maven, gradle, sbt etc.

Comment: [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'play' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'play': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: Hi @Jois, can look this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn) it tell you about your error, you might get something from it, and this is some dependecy is missing in your case only.

Comment: @ankushyadav I am damn sure too that this is a dependecy error!! but how do i fix this!! i have added all the jar files i can!! what jar files are you usin?

Comment: we are using maven build tool, we are not really trust on any IDE, which build tool r you using, because maven download internal dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may lack some dependencies.this is my aop demo pom it's work well.

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.release</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am using netbeans . what should i do to add this dependency?? create a xml file add add this code it?? And how can inject it to the project?