# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ServletRequestAttributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am getting below error on AWS box when deploying on tomcat8.
In my local system on tomcat8, it works fine.

**type** Exception report

**message** Servlet execution threw an exception

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.buildRequestAttributes(FrameworkServlet.java:996)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**My Tomcat lib dir**
[image]

Comment: did you added jars in deployment descriptor?

Comment: @HelloWorld where exactly in `deployment descriptor`, i have spring related jars inside `web-inf/lib`

Comment: did you add the spring web jar in the tomcat lib folder ? Please remove it. That jar should already be there in web app classpath.

Comment: `build path>configure build paty>click on deployment assembly>add>java build path entries(select all click ok)` its worth a shot

Comment: and yes remove jar from `tomcat`

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means that you have loaded different spring versions in your classpath. Could you post your maven pom or gradle configuration , or at least which spring jars are you deploying

Comment: @AntJavaDev it means your application cannot read the jar and in `web application` it happens if your deployment descriptor is missing jars to deploy with

Comment: @HelloWorld , you can try it locally , deploy a Spring Web App in Tomcat without the related jars , youll get a `ClassNotFoundException` , now deploy 2 versions of spring F.E. 3.2.5 and 4.2.0 ,  you ll get a `MethodNotFoundException` or a `NoClassDefFoundError` because at RunTime the JVM cannot decide which version to load. Read this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn) for more details