# Azure storage Blob -com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility error

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I have a program running that uses azure storage blobs. When it runs on a device that had java version 1.8.0_91 there is no error, but when it runs on a device that is java version 1.7.0_45, then it gives the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility
```

Could this error be because com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility is not supported in java 1.7 or could it be some other problem altogether.

Any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the [description](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java#minimum-requirements) of Azure Storage for Java on GitHub, the minimum requirement for JDK version is 1.6+. So I don't think the error was casued by not supporting in Java 1.7.

There are some SO threads below that I think their answer are useful & helpful for you to find out the issue reason and resolve it.

1. [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)
2. [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)
3. [How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Thankyou, but the problem is the program gives no error on one system, but gives on another. Another difference between the systems is that one runs Windows and the other Linux (gives the noclassdef errror).

Comment: @Aparna Thanks for your feedback. Seems that you post another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975896/getting-a-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-linux-platform-and-not-windows which I will try to help solving it.