# No job jar file set and Class WordCountMapper not found

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, word-count

I am running wordcount job from eclipse on `hadoop-2.6.0`.

While running I observed warning:

```
No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String)
```

and when program starts to run it throws error:

```
2017-05-04 21:44:43,019 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-05-04 21:44:45,340 INFO  [main] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032
2017-05-04 21:44:47,259 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(153)) - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2017-05-04 21:44:47,264 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(261)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-05-04 21:44:47,648 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(281)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-05-04 21:44:47,906 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(494)) - number of splits:2
2017-05-04 21:44:48,348 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:printTokens(583)) - Submitting tokens for job: job_1493908931599_0001
2017-05-04 21:44:48,671 INFO  [main] mapred.YARNRunner (YARNRunner.java:createApplicationSubmissionContext(371)) - Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
2017-05-04 21:44:49,006 INFO  [main] impl.YarnClientImpl (YarnClientImpl.java:submitApplication(251)) - Submitted application application_1493908931599_0001
2017-05-04 21:44:49,136 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:submit(1300)) - The url to track the job: http://ankita:8088/proxy/application_1493908931599_0001/
2017-05-04 21:44:49,137 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1345)) - Running job: job_1493908931599_0001
2017-05-04 21:45:19,717 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1366)) - Job job_1493908931599_0001 running in uber mode : false
2017-05-04 21:45:19,781 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1373)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2017-05-04 21:45:56,856 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1452)) - Task Id : attempt_1493908931599_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 8 more

2017-05-04 21:45:56,989 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1452)) - Task Id : attempt_1493908931599_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 8 more

2017-05-04 21:46:08,082 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1452)) - Task Id : attempt_1493908931599_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 8 more
2017-05-04 21:46:08,086 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1452)) - Task Id : attempt_1493908931599_0001_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 8 more

2017-05-04 21:46:15,147 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1452)) - Task Id : attempt_1493908931599_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 8 more

2017-05-04 21:46:16,160 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1452)) - Task Id : attempt_1493908931599_0001_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 8 more

2017-05-04 21:46:22,215 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1373)) -  map 100% reduce 100%
2017-05-04 21:46:25,251 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1386)) - Job job_1493908931599_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1493908931599_0001_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

2017-05-04 21:46:25,447 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1391)) - Counters: 13
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=99775
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=99775
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=99775
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=102169600
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

My source code is:

Mydriverclass:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class WordCount
      {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "WordCount");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
    }
```

MyMapper class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class WordCountMapper
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
             ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
 word.set(itr.nextToken());
 context.write(word, one);
}
}
}
```

MyReducer class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class WordCountReducer
extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
int sum = 0;
for (IntWritable val : values) {
 sum += val.get();
}
result.set(sum);
context.write(key, result);
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. First I created runnable jar file of wordcount code (specified in question) then I import that wordcount jar into my class path and I am able to run the program from eclipse to Hadoop remotely.