# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.JSGFPLib

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar, fingerprint

I want to build a class library in java . That means I want to develop a jar file which will be used in another java project .

In this class library project , I have written a class named FingerMatching . I am using JSGFPLib clas from FDxSDKPro.jar in FingerMatching class . JSGFPLib class is located in SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni package.

In FingerMatching class , there are two methods . The prototype of that two methods are as follows :

```
 public boolean fingerPrintIndetify(byte[] fingerData, byte[][] fingerEnrollData) 
 boolean fingerprintVerify(byte[] regMin, byte[] regMin1)
```

After building this class project , I have got a jar . Let the name of this jar is "FingerMatching.jar" . I have imported this jar to another project . After running that project , I am getting this error .

```
11-Feb-2018 12:08:15.899 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-77] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [FingerVerification] in context with path [/UFingerEnrollVerify] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.JSGFPLib
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at com.era.Fingerprint.FingerMatching.fingerprintVerify(FingerMatching.java:46)
    at com.era.Fingerprint.FingerMatching.fingerPrintIndetify(FingerMatching.java:31)
    at era.data.FingerPrintVerification.fingerVerfyFromTemplate(FingerPrintVerification.java:102)
    at era.servlet.FingerVerification.doPost(FingerVerification.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why am I getting this error ? Please help me to solve this error .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when your project does not have required runtime dependecies in the classpath. Does your `FingerMatching.jar` includes everything from `FDxSDKPro.jar`. If it does not, you have to also import `FDxSDKPro.jar` to the newly created project.

Comment: I have imported FDxSDKPro.jar in FingerMatching project .

Comment: @IccheGuri When you open `FingerMatching.jar` with  7zip (winrar or any other archive program), can you see content of `FDxSDKPro.jar` inside it.

Comment: No . I cant see content of FDxSDKPro.jar inside it

Comment: @IccheGuri Then you have to import FDxSDKPro.jar to your new project.

Comment: @SilverShroud i imported FDxSDKPro.jar and when i extract it i have all the content then also i got error when i  am creating war file and call JSGFPLib sgfplib = new JSGFPLib();