# Unity App Crash JAva Class not found and runtime exception error

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, crash, crash-reports

I recently published my first app over play store and now I got a crash report over the developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2567)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:1477)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1079)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2557)
```

Sadly I dont really know where to start to try and fix this or what could have caused this, since I dont know anything about java.

Maybe someone can at least give me a hint, where to start, would appreciate it a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Comment: Nothing in the exception seems to point at your code. Maybe the person exited the app as it was opening and crashed it?