# Add a jar to a Java program during runtime

Tags: java, jar, runtime

How to load a java lib to a running application dynamically?

I would like to add a dynamic lib (a jar file), so it is loaded.

For example, the program works well, however when the user tries to invoke specific functionality which needs logic present in the external lib, an exception is thrown:

> Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question, and it lacks search efforts

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URLClassLoader to load jar file. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html

Here is an example how to use this:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/urlclassloader/java-net-urlclassloader-example/

Note that you must use reflection after you dynamically load jar.