# External Jar is not working in SOAPUI getting ClassNotFoundError for Oracle Wsa Artifact while generatingstub

Tags: soapui

While generating code using Oracle artifact getting NoClassDefination found error. Also, try to copy required jar i.e. wsclient.jar inside bin/ext but it's no use same issue it's showing. 
Please suggest if anyone has a solution to create stub using oracle Artifact.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Comment: After you placed your jar in bin/ext did you restart SoapUI? What did you see in the log?

Comment: Sorry I didn't try out that. So after i generate stub using Apache.