# Java Class Not Found Exception with JsonFactory

Tags: java, json, maven, google-api, bukkit

So I am quite new to Java, and by that I mean like a week into Java, so a lot of it is still a mystery for me. 
Basically, I am making a SpigotMC plugin with Google API to fetch data from live streams. I am using Maven and when I run the programm there, it seems to work fine. However, when running it on an actual server, I get a weird error.

Here is the whole error message:

```
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'chatcontrol' in plugin MinecraftButChatRuinsEverything v0.1
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:710) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1641) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1481) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:47) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.aX(MinecraftServer.java:909) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:902) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:886) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:819) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
        at Commands.ChatControl.onCommand(ChatControl.java:33) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:81) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
        at Commands.ChatControl.onCommand(ChatControl.java:33) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-56f8471-eafd742]
```

I've seen people have the same problem, but I never saw a good or clear solution to that. I tried tinkering around on my own, but haven't had much success. I assume the problem is due to loading the classes somehow, but I have no idea what do with this information.

Here is the class in which the problem occurs after its getChatId method is called:

```
package Commands;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.LiveBroadcastListResponse;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class YouTubeLiveStreamAPI {
    static String streamID;
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS = "client_secret.json";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API code samples";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Create an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        File test = new File("src/main/resources/client_secret.json");
        System.out.println(test.exists());
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(test);
//        InputStream in = YouTubeLiveStreamAPI.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .build();
        Credential credential =
                new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Call function to create API service object. Define and
     * execute API request. Print API response.
     *
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException
     */
    public static void getChatId(String videoId)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();
        // Define and execute the API request
        YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.List request = youtubeService.liveBroadcasts()
                .list("snippet");
        LiveBroadcastListResponse response = request.setId(videoId).execute();
        YouTubeNormalChatAPI.chatId = response.getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getLiveChatId();
        YouTubeNormalChatAPI.getService();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new NormalChatTask();
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);
    }
}
```

And here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev212-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I know this is a long and complicated thing, but help would be really much appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be missing a class/package, com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well the thing is that I do have it imported and it works if I run the program normally. There is just some weird error when running it via spigot.

Comment: Did you create a jar first and then deployed it to your spigot server? If so, did you create the jar via mvn package?

Comment: @SteffenJacobs I did not, am I supposed to? What I did is just added it to dependencies and ran mvn install. If that's incorrect, instructions or link to some resource with instructions about the whole deploying thing would be much appreciated, as I am very unused to the whole Java and maven process.

Comment: Running mvn install should be fine as well. Currently I do not spot any obvious errors in your snippet. Could you maybe post the entire pom.xml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)