# Exception in Spring JUnit 5 test

Tags: spring, junit5

I have the following simple class

```
@Service
public class HearingInterpreter {

    private final WordProducer wordProducer;

    public HearingInterpreter(WordProducer wordProducer) {
        this.wordProducer = wordProducer;
    }

    public String whatIheard() {
        String word = wordProducer.getWord();

        System.out.println(word);

        return word;
    }
}
```

And the following configuration files

```
@Configuration
public class BaseConfig {

    @Bean
    HearingInterpreter hearingInterpreter(WordProducer wordProducer) {
        return new HearingInterpreter(wordProducer);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class LaurelConfig {

    @Bean
    LaurelWordProducer laurelWordProducer() {
        return new LaurelWordProducer();
    }

}
```

I wrote the following JUnit 5 based test class

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = {BaseConfig.class, LaurelConfig.class})
class HearingInterpreterTest {

    @Autowired
    HearingInterpreter hearingInterpreter;

    @Test
    void whatIheard() {
        String word = hearingInterpreter.whatIheard();

        assertEquals("Laurel", word);
    }

}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error(s)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy

```
at org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources(TestPropertySourceUtils.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:386)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:294)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:80)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:185)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:87)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:91)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:213)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:77)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassTestDescriptor.java:358)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassTestDescriptor.java:358)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:197)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:105)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources(TestPropertySourceUtils.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:294)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:80)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:185)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:89)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$11(ClassTestDescriptor.java:396)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$12(ClassTestDescriptor.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassTestDescriptor.java:396)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:221)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:118)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:118)
    ... 19 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 40 more

My pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>guru.springframework.petclinic</groupId>
    <artifactId>tb2g-testing-spring</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>

    <name>tb2g-testing-spring</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>*** FORK FROM ORIGINAL SPRING PROJECT TO DEMO TESTING FEATURES OF SPRING *** A Spring Framework application based on JSP, Spring MVC, Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and JDBC</description>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-petclinic/</url>

    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-data-jdbc.version>2.0.0.M1</spring-data-jdbc.version>

        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <!-- Version update should also be done in wro.xml, petclinic.less and static resources: htmlHeader.tag and footer.tag-->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.4.0</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>

        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
        <tomcat.version>9.0.14</tomcat.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
        <activation.version>1.1.1</activation.version>
        <servlet-api.version>4.0.1</servlet-api.version>
        <javax-jstl.version>1.2.2</javax-jstl.version>
        <taglibs-standard.version>1.2.5</taglibs-standard.version>

        <!-- Persistence -->
        <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Lovelace-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.14.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.4.1</hsqldb.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <assertj.version>3.11.1</assertj.version>
        <json-path.version>2.4.0</json-path.version>
        <mockito.version>2.23.4</mockito.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit-jupiter.version>

        <!-- Others -->
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>

        <!-- Maven plugins -->
        <jetty-maven-plugin.version>9.4.14.v20181114</jetty-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data-releasetrain.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
            <version>${taglibs-standard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  JSon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${json-path.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING, SPRING, SPRINGITY SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!--  because Spring Data usually comes with a slightly older version of Spring -->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- used for EhCacheCacheManager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database connection pool
        See here for more details on commons-dbcp versus tomcat-jdbc:
        http://blog.ippon.fr/2013/03/13/improving-the-performance-of-the-spring-petclinic-sample-application-part-3-of-5/
    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Java 11 support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>${activation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- Maven plugin versions are mentioned in order to guarantee the build reproducibility in the long term -->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>petclinic</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <!-- declared explicitly so Spring config files can be placed next to their corresponding JUnit test class  -->
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <Xlint/>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Specify the encoding for copying resources-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                    <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/petclinic/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                    <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/less</contextFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!--Needed for Java 11-->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>HSQLDB</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <db.script>hsqldb</db.script>
                <jpa.database>HSQL</jpa.database>
                <jdbc.driverClassName>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</jdbc.driverClassName>
                <jdbc.url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:petclinic</jdbc.url>
                <jdbc.username>sa</jdbc.username>
                <jdbc.password/>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: This may happen if you have conflicting Spring versions in the classpath. Check your dependency tree for spring artifacts with different versions.

Comment: I could not see anything obvious.

Comment: Please show your Maven pom  or GradLe build file.

Comment: Pom has been added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have not added **spring-core** dependency in your pom so you are getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on org.springframework.core try adding that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I removed the extra spring-test dependency, that did not help. I then added the spring-core dependency, that still did not work. Same error both times.

Comment: For Some reason, the clean did not work the first time. I re-cleaned and re-built. It is working now,

Comment: It's really unlikely you need to add spring-core because it's for sure already there transitively through [spring-data-jpa](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.0.RELEASE). If you run `mvn dependency:tree` you will find it.

Comment: If it's so then why the classnotfound exception occured on the core annotations

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is significantly different from `ClassNotFoundException`. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn) for details. Since `NoClassDefFoundError` was thrown, it means the class is there at compile time but at runtime, it cannot be resolved, usually due to version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the `spring-test` dependency. Actually your build gives a warning about it:

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for guru.springframework.petclinic:tb2g-testing-spring:war:5.1.0
>   'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-test:jar -> version ${spring-framework.version} vs 5.2.4.RELEASE @ line 302, column 15
>   It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

The relevant part of the `pom` you posted is:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring-framework.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <!-- ... -->
<properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Duplicated, should be removed. -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see, the artifact `spring-test` is being declared with two different versions. Removing the last one should be enough for it to work.