# Project packages cannot import Java compiler API: ClassNotFoundException / NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, java-compiler-api

I use Java compiler class inside my Spring Boot application as follows:

```
 String classStr = "\n" +
        "import java.util.List;\n" +
        "import java.util.Map;\n" +
        "import java.util.Arrays;\n"+
        "public class TestClass {\n" + String.join("\n",methods) + "}";

File root = new File("/src/main/resources/");
File sourceFile = new File(root, "TestClass.java");
sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), classStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null,sourceFile.getPath());

URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{root.toURI().toURL()});
cls = Class.forName("TestClass", true, classLoader);
```

It is working as expected and `cls` methods can be invoked without any problem.

Then I try to import and use a class inside my project src as follows:

```
String classStr = "\n" +
        "import java.util.List;\n" +
        "import java.util.Map;\n" +
        "import java.util.Arrays;\n"+
        "import com.nilanka.compilertest.Utility;\n"+
        "public class TestClass {\n" + String.join("\n",methods) + "}";
```

It gave me the error at the start:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Utility
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Then I tried:

```
compiler.run(null, null, null,
  -cp",Utility.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(),sourceFile.getPath());
```

then Application started without any error.

But when I try to execute a method from new class:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nilanka/compilertest/Utility
```

How can I resolve this problem?

I need a way to make the imports available in both compiling and runtime for the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Comment: No, this is a issue related to compiler API

Answer (score 0):

In the snippets you shared, there is no declaration of class and methods, you might not have defined it at all and. You can declare a class with the name `Cls`
It would go like this

```java
public class Cls{
      public static void main(String[]args){
           String classStr = "\n" +
            "import java.util.List;\n" +
            "import java.util.Map;\n" +
            "import java.util.Arrays;\n"+
            "public class TestClass {\n" + String.join("\n",methods) + "}";


           File root = new File("/src/main/resources/");
           File sourceFile = new File(root, "TestClass.java");
           sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
           Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), 
               classStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

           JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
           compiler.run(null, null, null,sourceFile.getPath());

           URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{                       
               root.toURI().toURL()});
           cls = Class.forName("TestClass", true, classLoader);
     }
}
```

Try running this. It might work :)