# NoClassDefError when accessing an Enum (org.inventivetalent.glow)

Tags: java, plugins, enums, minecraft, noclassdeffounderror

I am creating a spigot plugin and using an API called GlowAPI. The command I am trying to run is GlowAPI.setGlowing(Player player, GlowAPI.Color color, Collection<? extends Player> receivers).

The command is able to be called, but crashes when trying to get the GlowAPI.Color (which is a public static enum in the same package as the GlowAPI class), because "NoClassDefError". Below are snippets of my calls, my pom.xml, GlowAPI's enum and my error.

My Error:

`[21:54:48] [Server thread/WARN]: [MinecraftManhunt] Task #5 for MinecraftManhunt v1.3.3.9 generated an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.inventivetalent.glow.GlowAPI$Color at com.yoonicode.minecraftmanhuntplus.TaskManager.showGlow(TaskManager.java:92) ~[?:?] at com.yoonicode.minecraftmanhuntplus.PluginCommands$5.run(PluginCommands.java:178) ~[?:?] at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:82) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:415) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1255) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:428) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1206) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1034) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304) ~[spigot-1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3342-Spigot-3c40a6c-03b7252] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]`

My Call:

```
    for (Player player : main.runners)
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, Color.GREEN, main.runners);
    for (Player player : main.hunters)
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, Color.GREEN, main.hunters);
```

I don't understand why this is not working. The GlowAPI.setGlowing() is being called, but it can't seem to use the Color enum.

My pom.xml:

```
    <repository>
        <id>inventive-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.inventivetalent.org/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
```

Their enum:

```
    public static enum Color {
    BLACK(0, "0"),
    DARK_BLUE(1, "1"),
    DARK_GREEN(2, "2"),
    DARK_AQUA(3, "3"),
    DARK_RED(4, "4"),
    DARK_PURPLE(5, "5"),
    GOLD(6, "6"),
    GRAY(7, "7"),
    DARK_GRAY(8, "8"),
    BLUE(9, "9"),
    GREEN(10, "a"),
    AQUA(11, "b"),
    RED(12, "c"),
    PURPLE(13, "d"),
    YELLOW(14, "e"),
    WHITE(15, "f"),
    NONE(-1, "");
```

I've never come across this error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong or why this is being thrown. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show the content of `<dependency>` tag from you maven build file.

Comment: `
        <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>inventive-repo</id>
      <url>https://repo.inventivetalent.org/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
`


I dont know how to format this...

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding to comment. Also, I find the the xml to add GlowAPI github repo through jitpack is [different](https://pastebin.com/ttWDbGWe) form what you've posted.

Comment: I have already done this. This is what I have done from the beginning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)