# NoClassDefFoundError while integrating pdfbox jar file with siebel

Tags: java, pdfbox, noclassdeffounderror, siebel

I'm using pdfbox-app-2.0.25.jar file for pdf generation and it is working fine in eclipse but while integrating it to Siebel, getting error

`Error invoking service 'BTFLY B2B FTPV CAF Generation Service', method 'UserNameDesignation.doInvokeMethod' at step 'PDF Generation - FTPV'.(SBL-BPR-00162)--Class name incorrect or does not extend SiebelBusinessService : airtel/in/b2bcaf/FirstTimePhysicalVerification-- JVM Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont(SBL-EAI-05010)`

I had compiled all my jar file into JAVASE-1.6 and added required class paths.

Here is the list of libraries imported in my class

```
import com.siebel.data.SiebelPropertySet;
import com.siebel.eai.SiebelBusinessService;
import com.siebel.eai.SiebelBusinessServiceException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;   
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;   
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.AppendMode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
```

Comment: `and added required class paths` no you didn't, or Siebel ignores it, that's what it means. You need pdfbox and fontbox jar files in the classpath. Of the same version.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added PDFBox standalone jar file named pdfbox-app-2.0.25.jar on apache pdfbox website [link](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html). It already has pdfbox and fontbox jar inbulit in it.

Comment: That is fine too. Btw re classpath, some operating systems use ";" and some use ":" (important if you're using "java -cp ").

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Multiple jars are added in class path they are working fine but for this particular jar getting the error

Comment: Then it's time to try desperate things: 1) update / reinstall java 2) download the PDFBox jar files again. (also make sure no other versions are in the classpath) 3) try on a different system 4) check your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file if it mentions pdfbox

Comment: Seems there was some issue with the class path entry. Modified it and it's now fixed. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)