# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query

Tags: elasticsearch, noclassdeffounderror, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have below dependencies in the **child POM**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-elastic</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I have below dependencies in the parent POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting the above exception at calling of build() method in below code:

```
final AbstractAggregationBuilder aggregation =
        new MaxBuilder(ElasticConstant.Aggregation.MAX_DATE).field(ElasticConstant.Path.DATA
                + "." + DataChangeFilterType.APPROVAL_DATE.getBackEndMapping());

final AbstractAggregationBuilder aggregation2 =
        new MinBuilder(ElasticConstant.Aggregation.MIN_DATE).field(ElasticConstant.Path.DATA
                + "." + DataChangeFilterType.APPROVAL_DATE.getBackEndMapping());
                
final AbstractAggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = new NestedBuilder(ElasticConstant.Aggregation.DATES).path(ElasticConstant.Path.DATA).subAggregation(aggregation2).subAggregation(aggregation);

query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withIndices(this.mappingInfo.alias(organizationId))
        .withTypes(this.mappingInfo.objectType())
        .addAggregation(aggregationBuilder).withQuery(matchAllQuery())
        .build();
```

I get this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error:

nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query  exception:org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) |         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) |        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) |        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) |        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) |        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) |        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) |        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) |        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) |      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) |       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) |         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) |        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) |       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) |       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196) |        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) |      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) |      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) |    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) |        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366) |        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) |      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) |        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:847) |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1680) |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) |         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query |   at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.AbstractQuery.(AbstractQuery.java:37) |   at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQuery.(NativeSearchQuery.java:60) |   at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder.build(NativeSearchQueryBuilder.java:128)

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch 1.5.2 was released on April 27, 2015, Spring Data Elasticsearch  1.3.5 on September 20, 2016 and Spring Boot 1.3.8 on September 21 2016. None of these is in active support anymore.

You should update your dependencies to an actual version and see if this error persists.