# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, noclassdeffounderror

I am converting an old gradle prjoect to run in Java 11.
I made some small changes to the code & and added the dependencies from scratch in my build.gradle file.

While running the project I am struck at this error.

```
2022-04-05 12:04:19.985 ERROR 13556 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Binder
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getExcludeAutoConfigurationsProperty(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:231)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getExclusions(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:396)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:874)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:801)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:771)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.smartdocs.smartportal.LntSmartstoreApplication.main(LntSmartstoreApplication.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Here is my build.gradle file.

I am running the application on Spring boot version 1.5.12.RELEASE because there is usage of RelaxedPropertyResolver in my java code which was removed since Spring boot 2.0

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.smartdocs'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.2.4.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjtools', version: '1.6.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '3.3.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot
    //implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.6.4'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-core
    implementation group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-core', version: '3.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-graphite
    implementation group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-graphite', version: '3.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-healthchecks
    implementation group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-healthchecks', version: '3.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-jvm
    implementation group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-jvm', version: '3.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ryantenney.metrics/metrics-spring
    implementation group: 'com.ryantenney.metrics', name: 'metrics-spring', version: '3.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/client
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'client', version: '0.0.10'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient', version: '0.15.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_dropwizard
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_dropwizard', version: '0.15.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_servlet
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_servlet', version: '0.15.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-servlet
    implementation group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlet', version: '3.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'classmate', version: '1.5.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-schema
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-schema', version: '2.0.3'\
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-common
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-common', version: '3.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.6.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.10'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mongobee/mongobee
    implementation group: 'com.github.mongobee', name: 'mongobee', version: '0.13'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api
    implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder
    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '6.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-core
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-core', version: '1.1.4.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.social', name: 'spring-social-web', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fi.solita.clamav/clamav-client
    implementation group: 'fi.solita.clamav', name: 'clamav-client', version: '1.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.33.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.0.002'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.12.183'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '8.6.6'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-jackson2
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-jackson2', version: '1.20.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive
    implementation group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-drive', version: 'v3-rev197-1.25.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-credentials
    implementation group: 'com.google.auth', name: 'google-auth-library-credentials', version: '1.5.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http
    implementation group: 'com.google.auth', name: 'google-auth-library-oauth2-http', version: '0.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-storage', version: '2.4.5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20211205'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
    implementation group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk16
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcmail-jdk16', version: '1.46'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-config', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
    
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com

    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data', version: '4.1.3.RELEASE'
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlets', version: '4.0.0-alpha3'
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '1.5.12.RELEASE'
    
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-bean-validators
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-bean-validators', version: '2.9.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com


    
    
    //developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

defaultTasks 'bootRun'


sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.smartdocs.smartportal.LntSmartstoreApplication'

}
```

I am new at this work. Pls help me on this.

Comment: You are mixing Spring BOot 1.5, 2.2 and 2.6 that isn't going to work and you are managing some dependencies you shouldn't manage. Or in short, your dependencies are a bit of a mess.

Comment: thanks will try to  get  the springboot versions to same one. Can you point out few dependencies (atleast two or three) that I shouldn't manage..so that I can understand better.

Comment: `spring-beans`, `spring-data-mongodb` (and mongo dependencies) use `spring-boot-starter-data-mongo` instead. Metrics are part of `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and the version is managed by Spring. `validation-api` use `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead. The **Spring Social** project is dead and unsupported. You are also using SPring CLoud stuff which should come from a specific spring cloud version (which you should manage easier).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)