# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/view/MenuHost;

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

I'm making a google sign in process in my app.

Whenever I open my app it crashes and gives `NoClassDefFoundError`

I checked the logcat and found this:-

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2022-05-13 18:59:08.881 3810-3810/com.java.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.java.test, PID: 3810
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/view/MenuHost;
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1244)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.view.MenuHost" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.java.test-NhlLILW0268bo0W5tj1Gxw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.java.test-NhlLILW0268bo0W5tj1Gxw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95) 
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1244) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3183) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

This is `build.gradle(module)` :-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
            }
        }
        applicationId "com.java.test"
        compileSdkVersion 31
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Why this error is occurring?
Please help me!

Comment: Looks like proguard has renamed (or even removed) the classes mentioned in the error message that should not be renamed because they are needed. Configure Proguard to keep those classes.

Comment: I don't know much about Proguard. Where can I configure it? Note: I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Proguard is configured by the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` as shown in your gradle config.

Comment: The problem was not with Proguard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Comment: @DanubianSailor I got the solution of my problem while debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem while debugging.

The problem was in andoidx.appcompat class not found

In app build.gradle,
I changed this line of dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
```

To:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

Maybe the newer version has changed the classpath.

Comment: It also occurs on Android 13 and appcompat v1.6.0, downgrading to v1.5.0 solved the problem for me.