# Flink 1.15.2 Upgrade: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/table/api/bridge/scala/StreamTableEnvironment$

Tags: scala, apache-flink

When upgrading to Flink 1.15.2 I have the following dependencies. My project is built by Maven.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala-bridge_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to run a Flink app that converts a Table API to a DataStream. At the top of my App's main method I'm trying to create a StreamTableEnvironment, which will be used to do the conversions.

```
val env       = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val sTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
```

However the app throws an error, claiming it can not find the StreamTableEnvironment class, despite it being included.

```
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala.StreamTableEnvironment
```

Tried:

```
val env       = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val sTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
```

Expected: it to work

What happened:

```
    flink run -d transformer-payments-3.1-new.jar
    Using the result of 'hadoop classpath' to augment the Hadoop classpath: /etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.4.19.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.331.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/LICENSE.txt:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/NOTICE.txt:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/README.md:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/annotations-16.0.2.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.66.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/checker-qual-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.54.0.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/findbugs-annotations-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/ion-java-1.0.2.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/jmespath-java-1.12.331.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/cloudwatch-sink/lib/cloudwatch-sink-2.3.0.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/cloudwatch-sink/lib/cloudwatch-sink.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flink/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    2023-01-08 22:47:13,213 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                [] - Found Yarn properties file under /var/lib/flink/yarn/.yarn-properties-hadoop.
    2023-01-08 22:47:13,213 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                [] - Found Yarn properties file under /var/lib/flink/yarn/.yarn-properties-hadoop.
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/table/api/bridge/scala/StreamTableEnvironment$
    at io.benevity.data.PaymentsDataService$.main(PaymentsDataService.scala:32)
    at io.benevity.data.PaymentsDataService.main(PaymentsDataService.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:836)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1078)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1156)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala.StreamTableEnvironment$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Seems like You didn't update Your cluster to newer version of Flink ?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```