# Springboot upgrade to 3.2 and Open telemtry 1.26.0 has issues with compliation

Tags: java, open-telemetry, spring-boot-3

We had to upgrade our java applications to Spring Boot 3.2 and upon upgrade it is breaking the existing logging in honeycomb.

If I upgrade the Spring Boot to 3.2 and keep the version to 1.26.0, then I am facing many issues with ***SemanticAttributes with NoClassDefFoundError***.

```
[ERROR] /ObservableConfig.java:[13,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GlobalLoggerProvider
  location: package io.opentelemetry.api.logs
[ERROR] /ObservableConfig.java:[32,52] package io.opentelemetry.semconv.resource.attributes does not exist
```

I tried different versions and some of the were deprecated in newer versions and 1.27.0 is not available yet in our org repo and waiting for it in the meanwhile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Comment: I recommend you run a Maven dependency tree to identify potential versions conflicts. Likely Spring Boot relies on some newer OTEL version and you need to upgrade OTEL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot manages the otel version for you.
In most cases, you should not try to use a different version, because this will cause dependency issues like the one you see.